# R writing a function to avoid for loop

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Hi I am trying to learn ways in which I can avoid loops in my codes.

I have an example data here:

```
options(warn=-1) #Turning warnings off here
Company=c("A","C","B","B","A","C","C","A","B","C","B","A")
CityID=as.character(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4))
Value=c(120.5,123,125,122.5,122.1,121.7,123.2,123.7,120.7,122.3,120.1,122)
Sales=c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0)
df=data.frame(Company,CityID,Sales,Value)
df$new_value=0
```

I also created a custom function (simple example only for testing purposes) as below.

```
funcCity12 = function(data){
  data_new=data[which(data$CityID == '1'|data$CityID == '2'),]
  for (i in 1:nrow(data_new)){
    data_company=df[(df$Company)==data_new[i,'Company'] & !df$CityID==1 & !df$CityID==2,]
    data_new[i,'new_value'] = max(data_company[data_company$Sales==1,]$Value) #Note we take the maximum value here
  }
  data_new
}

df2=funcCity12(data=df) # obtaining the result here
```

Now I am trying to write a function to avoid the for loop in the previous function.

```
funcCity12_no_loop = function(x,df){
  data_company=df[(df$Company)==x[,'Company'] & !df$CityID==1 & !df$CityID==2,]
  x[,'new_value'] = max(data_company[data_company$Sales==1,]$Value) #Note we take the maximum value here
  x
}

funcCity12_no_loop(x=df[1,],df=df) #Output for the first row of df1
```

This seems to be working when I input the rows individually. What I am stuck at is how to run this function for all rows of the dataframe. I am not sure if the 2nd function requires more changes for this purpose. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

P.S. For the second function, my initial reaction was to create a for loop and loop through the observations, but that defeats the whole purpose.

**EDIT**

This is based on @eonurk's answer

```
zz=apply(df,1, function(x){ 
  data_company=df[(df$Company)==x[1] & !df$CityID==1 & !df$CityID==2,]
  x[5] = max(data_company[data_company$Sales==1,]$Value) #Note we take the maximum value here
  x
})
```

Output is shown below:

[image]

Comment: More than the `for` loop in your original function, I see a scoping problem there: you only have an argument (`data`), but inside the function definition there's also `df` which, by the scoping rules, will be called from `.GlobalEnv`. This is, in general, considered a bad practice.

Comment: @PavoDive Thank you for pointing this out. Your are right. The first function does not supply df. However, please note that for the second function (the one without the for loop), I do have the df part in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apply function to reach out each individual observation of your dataframe.

For instance, you can multiplicate Values and Sales columns for no reason at all with following:

```
apply(df,1, function(x){ as.numeric(x["Sales"])*as.numeric(x["Value"])})
```

Edit:

Now you just need to use `dplyr` package

```
zz=apply(df,1, function(x){ 
  data_company=df[(df$Company)==x[1] & !df$CityID==1 & !df$CityID==2,]
  x[5] = max(data_company[data_company$Sales==1,]$Value) #Note we take the maximum value here
  x
}) %>% as.data.frame %>% t
```

Comment: well, the function I wrote is a "custom function" that multiplies two numbers for each row of the dataset you provided. You just need to change inside the brackets.

PS: I hope you got the point. Best!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am quite new to this and did not get what was going on. I edited you code a bit and this is what I came up with. The problem that I see with this approach is that what I get back from the operation is not a dataframe. Additionally, everything turns to a character. Should this be happening here? (I am posting the code I wrote with your comment in my answer). It would be time consuming to format the data every time I use this function. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: With dplyr package, you can just reformat it. Just add `%>% as.data.frame` to the end of your function. If you want the transpose of it just add `%>% t` to its tail. I added to my answer. 
If you liked the solution, please consider accepting as an answer, so that it won't be in the unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way without a loop. First we filter based on your criteria, then we group by company and calculate the max, then we join the dataframe to the original dataset (also filtered based on your criteria). I didn't make it a function, but the building blocks are all there.

```
library(tidyverse)

list(
df %>%
  filter(CityID %in% 1:2) %>%
  select(-new_value),
df %>%
  filter(! CityID %in% 1:2 & Sales == 1) %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  summarise(new_value = max(Value))
) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "Company")
#>   Company CityID Sales Value new_value
#> 1       A      1     1 120.5        NA
#> 2       C      1     1 123.0     123.2
#> 3       B      1     0 125.0     120.7
#> 4       B      2     0 122.5     120.7
#> 5       A      2     0 122.1        NA
#> 6       C      2     1 121.7     123.2
```